# Trouble with MIPS Programming

Tags: mips

I'm trying to figure out how to set a base register ($t0) to the start of the data segment 0x10010000.

I am beyond lost.
Thanks,

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. It's clear it's about MIPS from the tag you used, and if you weren't having trouble you wouldn't be posting here. Removing that irrelevant information leaves the title blank. Your question title should be descriptive enough to be useful to a future reader seeing it in a search result.

Comment: The clean way to do this is to have `.data`, followed _immediately_ by (e.g.) `datastart:`. Then, do `la $t0,datastart`, rather than hardwiring the address

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it simply:

```
li $t0, 0x10010000
```

Am I missing something about the question?

li is load immediate, which loads the value on the right to the destination register in the middle.